# It works fine on Jupyter but not in VSC

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I tried the following code in Jupyter and works fine. However, in VSC code I got this absurd error: `invalid literal for int() with base 10`.

[code in VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIwDG.png)

[the same code in Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDi09.png)

Comment: try adding ```print(recent)``` just before the ```int()``` call.  if the exception is thrown look at the console to see what the offending input was.

Comment: looks like you could delete the ```gKeyword``` assignment altogether in the VSC code.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not the same.  `keyword_to_csv` is a global level functon in your jupyter notebook, and it's a class member in the VSC code.  The PROiBLEM here is that you have skipped a `self` parameter in all your class methods.  So, when you call `tw.keyword_to_csv('Covid')`, Python ends up passing `tw` as the first parameter, and "Covid" as the second parameter.  When you try to convert "Covid" to an integer, it unsurprisingly fails.

You need

```
    def keyword_to_csv(self, keyword, recent):
```

and the same for the rest of the class methods.